# How the language is created? (Fundamental question rather than solidity)

Tags: immutable

I am curious about how 'immutable' and 'constant' commands enable users not to change after the declaration. Should I compile it into assembly language to know that? How the language is created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those variables that are *not* `immutable` or `constant` are assigned a storage "slot" by the compiler. There is a storage namespace in the blockchain that the contract reads from and writes to as directed by the executable code. So the compiler basically reduces the source code to step-by-step instructions to access this storage.

`constant` variables are written to the bytecode itself, in place. Wherever the variable name symbol appears in the source code, the compiler replaces it with the "constant" value instead of storage instructions. No storage is accessed and it can't be modified, ever.

`immutable` is a storage variable that is protected from updates.

Hope it helps.